# angular material vertical stepper separate label and content section

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

[image]

If i add this css:

```
mat-step-header{
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: flex-end ;
}
```

I am trying to get [this stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview) to work.

I used angular material design for vertical stepper. How can I make the stepper title on the left and content to right side like the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_vertical_tabs.asp).

or is there any module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieved my design. Hope this will use for anyone.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-vertical-stepper #stepper [@.disabled]="true">
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
      <h2> Step 1</h2>
      <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
    </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 2">
    Step 2
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 3">
    Step 3
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step label="Step 4">
    Step 4
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step label="Step 5">
    Step 5
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 6">
    Step 6
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </div>
    </mat-step>

</mat-vertical-stepper>
<div >
  <ul>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 0}"><a (click)="move(0)">Label 1</a></li>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 1}"><a (click)="move(1)">Label 2</a></li>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 2}"><a (click)="move(2)">Label 3</a></li>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 3}"><a (click)="move(3)">Label 4</a></li>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 4}"><a (click)="move(4)">Label 5</a></li>
  <li class="mytest" [ngClass]="{'active': stepper.selectedIndex == 5}"><a (click)="move(5)">Label 6</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatStepper} from '@angular/material';

export class implements OnInit {
  isLinear = false;

  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
   ngOnInit() {
   }
    move(index: number) {
    this.stepper.selectedIndex = index;
  }
}
```

Thats all.

Used from: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-demo-matstepper-move?file=app%2Fdemo%2Fdemo.component.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]Apply below flex  properties to your mat-step-header which will only align header to the right

```
mat-step-header{
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: flex-end ;
}
```

Comment: But this is not achieve the exact my design. Because all the content elements are displayed below the header. I want all the heading should be in right. All content should start from the top of the position.

Comment: @vinotha So you what the title to be as it is in example but the content to be at right?

Comment: Plz see my img ref.

Answer (score 0):

The Above solution, worked for me with slight modification. I used mat-side nav and mat-stepper to achieve the below design. 
[image]

You also must be wondering where is the header, I removed by adding this CSS in styles.css

```html
.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: none !important;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

use below HTML code for achieving this design with the above solution.

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened class="example-sidenav" [fixedInViewport]="options.value.fixed"
        [fixedTopGap]="options.value.top">
        <mat-nav-list>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(0)">Contract Essential Details</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(1)">Terms and conditions</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(2)">Lines</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(3)">Commitments</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(4)">Assets</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(5)">License</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(6)">Consumption Chart</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(7)">Renewal</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(8)">Artifacts</a>
            <a mat-list-item (click)="move(9)">Version Control</a>
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [@.disabled]="true">
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button mat-raised-button (click)="stepper.reset()" style="float: right;">Reset</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Contract Essential Details</h2>
                <div id="u1475">10% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=10></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>

             

            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Terms and conditions</h2>
                <div id="u1475">20% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=20></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
               
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
                <div>
                    <button mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Lines</h2>
                <div id="u1475">30% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=30></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
                
                
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Contract Commitments</h2>
                <div id="u1475">40% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=40></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
                
               
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Assets</h2>
                <div id="u1475">50% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=50></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
                
            </mat-step>

            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">License</h2>
                <div id="u1475">60% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=60></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
                
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Consumption Chart</h2>
                <div id="u1475">70% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=70></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
               
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>
                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Renewal</h2>
                <div id="u1475">80% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=80></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
              
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperNext style="float: right;">Next</button>

                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Artifacts</h2>
                <div id="u1475">90% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=90></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
            </mat-step>
            <mat-step>
                <div>
                    <button  mat-raised-button matStepperPrevious style="float: right;">Back</button>

                </div>
                <h2 mat-dialog-title id="u1469">Version Control</h2>
                <div id="u1475">100% Complete
                </div>
                <div style="width: 182px;">
                    <mat-progress-bar value=100></mat-progress-bar>
                </div>
               
            </mat-step>

        </mat-horizontal-stepper>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need as you and i found another solution that is very simple. You can use the Horizontal stepper and apply float left to *.mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container* and float right to *.mat-horizontal-content-container*.